# How to create a JSON document using Java?

Tags: java, json

I want to read data from the database, convert it to docs (JSON) using Java.

Thanks

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library) about which Java JSON libraries to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**GSON** is a Java library from Google to convert Java objects to JSON. You can simply pass a Java object to the library function and it will return a JSON string.

**Download**: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

**Example**: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

I have used the library from http://www.json.org, but the whole thing seems to be tedious to me. GSON is simple to use IMHO.

Comment: I have also used StringTree's JSON easily with no issues. www.stringtree.org/stringtree-json.html

Comment: Jackson is a popular alternative to GSON. The APIs are quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

I would use JSONObject class:

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

or you can build the string.